# How to Assign or store Model's table name into variable in laravel (this is for filter functionality)?

Tags: php, laravel

How to Assign or store Model's table name into a variable in laravel (this is for filter functionality)?

```
$query = new LiveClasses;
if (request('language')) {
    // die("333");
    $query->where('language_used', '=', request('language'));
}
if (request('start') && request('last')) {
    // die("333");
    $first  = 'sub_price_1 >= ' . request('start');
    $second = 'sub_price_1 <= ' . request('last');
    $query->whereRaw($first)->whereRaw($second);
}
if (request('rating')) {
    // die("&rating=5&start=150&last=1264");
    $query
        ->leftJoin('reviews', 'reviews.reviewable_id', '=', 'live_classes.id')
        ->Where('rating', request('rating'))
        ->Where('reviewable_type', '=', 'App\Models\LiveClasses');
    // $courses = Review::where('rating', request('rating'))
    //     ->leftJoin('live_classes', 'reviews.reviewable_id', '=', 'live_classes.id')
}
$courses = $query->paginate(9);
```

Answer (score 0):

To get the name of model table use `->getTable()` eloquent method.

To get the morphable class name (type) use `->getMorphClass()` eloquent method.

```
$query = new LiveClasses;

if (request('language')) {
    $query->where('language_used', '=', request('language'));
}

if (request('start') && request('last')) {
    $first  = 'sub_price_1 >= ' . request('start');
    $second = 'sub_price_1 <= ' . request('last');
    $query->whereRaw($first)->whereRaw($second);
}

if (request('rating')) {
    $reviewTable = (new Review)->getTable();

    $query
        ->leftJoin($reviewTable, reviewTable . '.reviewable_id', '=', $query->getTable() . '.id')
        ->where('rating', request('rating'))
        ->where('reviewable_type', '=', $query->getMorphClass());
}

$courses = $query->paginate(9);
```

Comment: not working , This is not working  $query = new LiveClasses;                                               this $query not append and not making query and i am not get correct object.